# Unable to log function output with Out-File nor Add-Content

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to log a function output into a file.. But both Out-File and Add-Content comes out with an empty file. Any advise?

```
function Print-Date {
    $DateFormat = get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
    Write-Host ("Hello! `nTHE DATE FORMAT IS: " + $DateFormat)
    }
Print-Date | Out-File .\ScriptLog.txt -append
```

Also, is there a difference between "Out-File -append" and ">>" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write-Host only writes to the console, not to the output stream. Use Write-Output instead.

Comment: That's my problem! Thanks!!